# Code mysteriously end in middle of function (serialport datareceived handler)

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I have a SerialPort `DataReceived` event handler in C# code:

```
void serPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = "";
    while (sp.ReadBufferSize > 0) {
        int bytes = sp.ReadBufferSize;
        char[] result = new char[bytes];
        sp.Read(result, 0, bytes);
        indata += new string(result).Replace("\0", "");
    }
    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => port1out.Text += indata + "\n"));
}
```

Using breakpoints, I know that the funtion is called, while loop is being executed, even `indata` variable contains received data, but when the while loop ends, the whole listener ends. No text is added to `port1out` textbox. I tried to add nothing-doing code after(and before too) the Dispatcher.Invoke.... line, use breakpoint and it's not executed - code just ends after while loop.
Why? Why isn't the whole statement executed?

Comment: Are you sure that execution control doesn't block in the sp.Read(...) line?

Comment: Any exceptions?  Note that in C# 5, the best way to read from a serial port is `BaseStream.ReadAsync`, which you can `await` and not have to do `Dispatcher.Invoke` manually, the runtime will take care of making sure your completion routine runs in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will never end because [`ReadBufferSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will never be zero.  You are misunderstanding what `ReadBufferSize` means.  It is not the amount of data waiting to be read, but the maximum amount of data the `SerialPort` class will hold (or buffer) while it waits for you to read out.  What you should be looking at instead is the [`BytesToRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

You can also call the [`ReadExisting()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting(v=vs.110).aspx) method as is shown on the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: While you have correctly identified why the textbox never updates, your suggested fix is suboptimal.  Setting a correct timeout in conjunction with `BaseStream.ReadAsync` works 1000 times better than `BytesToRead`/`ReadExisting`/`DataReceived`.

Comment: I was wondering why the byte array is much longer and full of empty chars...  So I changed readbuffersize to bytestoread and in while is now only `indata+= sp.ReadExisting()`. I was readexisting using before, but it has no timeout, so it couldn't read whole incoming data. So I changed to read bytes, then added while... But now it's working with while.

Answer (score 0):

Throw away the DataReceived event, and just do this instead:

```
void ReadFromPort(SerialPort p)
{
     Stream s = p.BaseStream;
     s.ReadTimeout = 20;
     // 1/50th of a second and 10 serial bits per byte
     byte[] buffer = new byte[p.BaudRate / 500];
     ReadSerialStream(s, buffer);
}

void async ReadSerialStream(Stream s, byte[] buffer)
{
     int bytesRead = await s.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     string indata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                              buffer.Take(bytesRead).Where(b => b != 0).ToArray());
     port1out.Text += indata + Environment.Newline;
     ReadSerialStream(s, buffer);
     // or use an infinite while loop. With async methods, recursion is safe
}
```

Actually having a read in progress will make virtual serial ports actually start transferring data.  If you instead rely on `DataReceived` and `BytesToRead`, your data may get stuck in (for example) USB transfer buffers, and never reach the serial port object.  Or you may end up with multiple USB transfers for each individual byte (first reporting the "buffer not empty" flag, then transferring the buffer content).  `ReadAsync` is more efficient at all levels.  Also, it works within the async/await paradigm to receive serial events directly on the UI thread, so you don't have to mess with cross-thread calls or synchronizing access to internal data structure.